# Raspberry Pi / ARM Emulation

Tags: virtualization, arm, qemu, raspberrypi, linaro

I'd like to be able to boot an image of Raspbian Wheezy, for example.

I've seen people using QEMU but they have to download Linux source and compile it or accept a pre-compiled one from an untrusted website. I could run this untrusted VM code in a VM but it seems silly.
Also trying to run the Windows version of QEMU with Wine seems silly.

Is there a way to emulate without a kernel module, or some other easy to use approach?

I also see [Linaro is used for Firefox OS development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment), but I don't see a report of anyone using it for Rasp Pi emulation.

Comment: Doesn't the `qemu-system-arm` package provide ARM emulation?

Comment: Yes I think it helps, though directions like http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/ require additional binaries (other than whichever OS image file). If there is a way to make it work without, that could be a good answer.